# How to get SQL Server to return a default of 0, if no rows exist?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

How can I get a default value of 0 if a sum does not return any rows?

Edit: I have edited this post to add a more thorough example (which the previous one didn't encounter)

E.g.

```
 DECLARE @Item TABLE
(
    Id int,
    Price decimal,
    PricePer decimal
)

DECLARE @OrderItem TABLE
(
    Id int,
    ItemId int,
    ChargedPrice nvarchar(10),
    QtyRequired int,
    QtyLeftToDespatch int
)

INSERT INTO @Item (Id,Price,PricePer) VALUES (1,1.00, 1)
INSERT INTO @Item (Id,Price,PricePer) VALUES (2,2.00, 1)
INSERT INTO @Item (Id,Price,PricePer) VALUES (3,3.00, 1)
INSERT INTO @Item (Id,Price,PricePer) VALUES (4,4.00, 1)

INSERT INTO @OrderItem (Id, ItemId,ChargedPrice,QtyRequired,QtyLeftToDespatch) VALUES ( 1,1,100,100,50 )
INSERT INTO @OrderItem (Id, ItemId,ChargedPrice,QtyRequired,QtyLeftToDespatch) VALUES ( 2,1,200,300,50)
INSERT INTO @OrderItem (Id, ItemId,ChargedPrice,QtyRequired,QtyLeftToDespatch) VALUES ( 3,1,300,300,50 )

DECLARE @ItemIdTest int 
SET @ItemIdTest = 4

SELECT SUM((price/priceper)*QtyRequired) as total_value,
       SUM((price/priceper)*QtyRequired) as outstanding_value
FROM @Item i
INNER JOIN @OrderItem o ON i.Id = o.ItemId
WHERE i.Id = @ItemIdTest
group by itemId
```

This will return

```
total_value, outstanding_value
==============
<No rows>
```

But I want it to have 0 as the default value returned. However, if you do a SELECT to select it, then a second SELECT to select a default, 2 result sets will be returned.

Can I do it just in one? I have looked at COALESCE, but this only works if NULL is returned, which it isn't.

**Edit**: I think the problem is to do with the group with, but is there a reason why still it doesn't come back with any results?

Comment: I have changed the example, which experiences the error, rather than the one I created before

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
 DECLARE @Item TABLE
(
    Id int,
    Price decimal,
    PricePer decimal
)

DECLARE @OrderItem TABLE
(
    Id int,
    ItemId int,
    ChargedPrice nvarchar(10),
    QtyRequired int,
    QtyLeftToDespatch int
)

INSERT INTO @Item (Id,Price,PricePer) VALUES (1,1.00, 1)
INSERT INTO @Item (Id,Price,PricePer) VALUES (2,2.00, 1)
INSERT INTO @Item (Id,Price,PricePer) VALUES (3,3.00, 1)
INSERT INTO @Item (Id,Price,PricePer) VALUES (4,4.00, 1)

INSERT INTO @OrderItem (Id, ItemId,ChargedPrice,QtyRequired,QtyLeftToDespatch) VALUES ( 1,1,100,100,50 )
INSERT INTO @OrderItem (Id, ItemId,ChargedPrice,QtyRequired,QtyLeftToDespatch) VALUES ( 2,1,200,300,50)
INSERT INTO @OrderItem (Id, ItemId,ChargedPrice,QtyRequired,QtyLeftToDespatch) VALUES ( 3,1,300,300,50 )

DECLARE @ItemIdTest int 
SET @ItemIdTest = 4

SELECT COALESCE(SUM((price/priceper)*QtyRequired),0) as total_value,
       COALESCE(SUM((price/priceper)*QtyRequired),0) as outstanding_value
FROM @Item i
LEFT OUTER JOIN @OrderItem o ON i.Id = o.ItemId
WHERE i.Id = @ItemIdTest
group by itemId
```

Comment: when you e.g. SET @ItemIdTest = 5 (non existing itemId) it will return empty rows

Comment: I think he needs to re-think the design of his app!

Comment: +1 actually looking again at your solution it seems that it should work for this problem

Comment: I would not make sense to expect 0 when asking about itemId that does not exist at all like 5 ( no rows returned then)as opposed to ItemId not present in any orders (0 returned)

Comment: Why is it a design problem to get the totals? Surely it shows we are considering all possibilities?

I've over-simplified it here. The reason for this query is to find out how much money is to be owed to a supplier substituted with item in here). But the idea is to give the query a supplier ID, and the query returns the amount of money outstanding for this supplier (instead of the item).

Doesn't seem like a design flaw to me?

Answer (score 13):

Try this

```
SELECT ISNULL(SUM(Debt) ,0)
FROM SupplierDebt
WHERE Id = @TestId
```

Answer (score 10):

Or use

```
SELECT COALESCE(SUM(Debt) ,0)
FROM SupplierDebt
WHERE Id = @TestId
```

COALESCE is an ANSI standard, if that bothers you and can take multiple parameters.

Answer (score 2):

SQL 2k5: this worked for me:

```
isnull(sum(Dept), 0)
```